# How to track outbound clicks from an rss feed

Tags: rss, outbound

I want to track outbound clicks from different rss feeds which are fetched and displayed as links on my site. (popurls.com type site) 
Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a platform such as [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en), which would handle all this for you.

That link is to a support page with instructions on link tracking.

Comment: Thanks. i have added the first code, but unsure where and how to add this onclick attribute:<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com' ); return false;">Check out example.com</a>

Comment: @merxie the onclick attribute should be added to every link you want to track. Alternatively, you may user jQuery to add the tagging automatically, something like $("a").each(function(){ $(this).click(function(){ trackOutboundLink( $(this).attr('href')) }) }) But be aware that you need additional rules to exclude internal links, this example jQuery script will add the trackOutboundLink function to every <a> tag it finds.

Comment: Add `onClick` to any of your link tags like this: `<a href="//www.example.com" onClick="trackOutboundLink('//www.example.com');return false;">Example</a>`